# Battery life impact with fast charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, mobile

Typically fast charging reduces backup time and life. Now a days almost all handsets are coming up with different fast charging capabilities. I'm currently using Galaxy Note9 which has fast charging features as well. 
When I connect the supplied charger it starts charging with fast charging always. Fast charging is really helpful. But when I charge my phone at night while sleeping, it also uses fast charging. My question is during night time, fast charging is not required and normal charging is beneficial. So, why the manufacturer doesn't keep normal charging mode so that it can be used at night time  for getting better backup time and better battery life.

Comment: The chargers aren't smart enough, as that would make them more expensive.

Comment: Also, the manufacturers sell new phones, so as long as you are willing to buy it they have little incentive to extend the lifespan of the device (witness then lack of user exchangeable batteries in modern phones).

Comment: You're asking why a phone manufacturer doesn't include yet another obviously useful feature? There's a plethora of stuff that is not included as simple as disabling the proximity sensor and even a restart button. Not to mention, have you seen how most people treat their phones anyways? Plug your phone into a current limited outlet. My phone charges way slower from my PC than my wall outlet and my phone can tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this functionality in a Dell XPS laptop BIOS, a sort of a calendar where you can set days/times where fast or normal charging is used. Not for phones though. The closest you can get is to have two chargers - one capable of delivering maximum current and another "dumb" 100-500 mA, and use the latter one at night. I started doing this as soon as I realized that charging can't be tuned in the phone. The results are promising so far - my phone is on the same battery for 3+ years going strong, while the same age and model operated by my SO is at the end of the second one :-).

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why fast charging is not advisable to be used always is due to the heat generated by supplying higher than usual current that the battery normally experiences. If the phone has a good enough heat dissipation capacity from the battery to the outside world, it's normally okay to use fast charging always.

Also, if you keep the battery temperature low, fast charging will not reduce battery capacity. Charge-discharge cycles will.

Comment: So, you mean to say now a days Phones are manufactured with better heat dissipation capability and hence there is no negative impact.

Comment: As long as they can keep the battery temperature down, then yes. There is no negative impact. [Quoted from https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/capacity_loss] "The aging process of lithium-ion is cell oxidation, a process that occurs naturally as part of usage and aging, and cannot be reversed."